# In the Monaco editor, how do I get the selected text from the IEditor interface

Tags: monaco-editor

Getting lost in the API with it's very telegraphic documentation.  How do I get the selected text from the IEditor interface?  The `selection` object returned by `getSelection`only has line and column numbers.  Do i then need to search in the editor's text for the text?

And, what is the primary selection as opposed to all other selections returned by `getSelections`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quite a few monaco-editor APIs work with ranges or spans. Using a range you can get the text in that range from `editor.getModel().getValueInRange()`.

About multiple selections: monaco-editor supports multiple selections. You first select some text without a modifier key, which becomes the primary selection. Then you add secondary selections by holding <kbd>alt</kbd> (<kbd>opt</kbd> on macOS) while dragging a new range.

Comment: You can also use the universal window.getSelection().toString().  This will get the selected text anywhere in the window, including the monaco control.

Comment: @juls This won't work in Firefox though, at least for me